# How can I run codeception via browser without using php exec

Tags: php, web, codeception

I am currently creating an automated test website where all codeception test logs can be shown. My server runs codeception through cron but the user should be able to run the test manually. My question is can I use codeception class in a php webpage without executing the commandline version? If possible anyone have an idea how?

Comment: Have you seen Webception? https://github.com/jayhealey/Webception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, it is actually also quite simple. Codeception uses the symfony console component for their command line tool. Take a look at the `\Codeception\Command\Run::execute()` method on how they do it. It can be a bit overwhelming at first glance, but in the end it boils down to this piece of code:

```php
$this->codecept = new Codecept($userOptions);

if ($suite and $test) {
    $this->codecept->run($suite, $test);
}
```